# Get the amount of pictures from device

Tags: android

I'm developing an application about data in device like count sms, mails. I can't find the way to get the amount of pictures.

How can I get the amount of pictures stored in the device? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: U can loop through directories and files and get the total count.

Comment: Who upvoted this question? What possible reason is there to do so?

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Maybe somebody who was also interested in this? Do no ask such a useless question pls. To chaim: you could search all directories of your device and check if a file has an ending of like .jpg or .png or .gif or whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a query.

Something like this (this code was not intended for this goal, however i think this is the way to go):

```
Uri imagesUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external"); // for SD Card only
String[] fields = {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
    };

Cursor cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(
        imagesUri, 
        fields, 
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA+" = '*'" ,
        null,
        null);
num_images = cursor.getCount();
```

I didn't try this, i used something like this to get all ordered images from a folder.

Try using directly the COUNT keyword in the query.
Hope this helps.